# Allowing inventory stock count reduction only for completed Orders in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm currently facing an issue in WooCommerce where the inventory stock count is being reduced immediately after a customer places an order. However, I would like to change this behavior and implement a system where the stock quantity remains unchanged until I manually confirm the order from the WooCommerce dashboard.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could kindly provide me with a code snippet or guidance on how to achieve this functionality. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to confirm orders from the dashboard before the inventory stock count is reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is allowing inventory stock count reduction only when an order status is set as "completed" by the Shop manager, using the following code snippet:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels', 10 );
function custom_wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels(){
    // remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
    
    add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels' );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). it should work.

Based on WooCommerce some core functions [`wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels( $order_id )`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/7.7.0/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-stock-functions.php#L86-L115) and [`wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels( $order_id )`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/7.7.0/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-stock-functions.php#L117-L144), that are involved in managing stock levels for order items within an order.