# WooCommerce delay decrementing stock on payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

does anyone know in woocommerce is there a way to delay stock being reduced after an order is placed

we are having a bit of an issue where the stock decrease can slow the customer down when checking out,

so if we can defer the stock decrease until after the user has reached the thank you page that would be great

Comment: isn't it would be easier just increase stock amount in dashboard to +n that will cover average orders?  shouldnt be big number i guess

Comment: May be this answer code could help: [Allowing inventory stock count reduction only for completed Orders in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321233/allowing-inventory-stock-count-reduction-only-for-completed-orders-in-woocommerc/76321869#76321869)